# Node.js ignoring get handler for root of site

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js server whose setup is simplified the below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');

// Files in public are static
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
// Serve icon
app.use(favicon(path.resolve('./public', 'Pictures', 'favicon.ico')));

http.createServer(app, function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Hello world');

}).listen();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    let b = someFunction();
    if(b){
       res.redirect('/option/one');
    }
    else{
         res.redirect('option/two');
    }

})
```

I have this running on a web hosting service and when I access my website at e.g. [www.myDomain.com](http://www.myDomain.com) what I want is to be either redirected to myDomain.com/option/one or myDomain.com/option/two. However what happens instead, is that myDomain.com responds with index.html from my 'public' directory and does not redirect me.

I've found this does not happen if I remove the two lines

```
// Files in public are static
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
// Serve icon
app.use(favicon(path.resolve('./public', 'Pictures', 'favicon.ico')));
```

however just removing them is not a good solution, as public contains many files (javascript, stylesheets, html, pictures etc.) which require each other across each other and making a node.js get handler for each of those seems like the suboptimal solution. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this either you can do this. This will set the default to false.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public'), {
    index: false
}));
```

Another way is to change the order of your code. Put the

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
```

after the / get function.